# Is it possible to get the nth item in a tuple?

Tags: vb.net, tuples

I am passing a few optional arguments to a function as a tuple, since all of these have to be passed together or not at all. I would like to be able to iterate over the elements of the tuple numerically, and perform an operation on each item. For example:

```
Public Function myFunction(Optional t As Tuple(Of Integer, String, SomeType) = Nothing) As Integer
    For i = 0 to 2
        someCollection(i).someMethod(t(i)) 'Pseudocode for accessing ith item in tuple
    Next
End Function
```

One way to resolve the problem would be to use a list, but then I lose the ability to enforce the number of members (which will always be fixed) and the types of each member. Another way would be to write out the statement three times with `t.Item1`, `t.Item2` etc, but this is ugly.

Is there any way to access the `nth` item in a tuple?

Note: I would like to accomplish this with a tuple if at all possible, even though I am aware I could create alternate method signatures.

Comment: If you need to iterate over a `Tuple`, you should probably be using an array. The same statement three times seems appropriate.

Comment: @rynah All the elements in an array need to be of the same type.

Comment: Yes, and you’d make that type `Object`, because you don’t care what’s in them as long as they have `ToString` (or whatever the case may be). Alternatively, iterate over `New Object() {t.Item1, t.Item2, t.Item3}`.

Comment: @rynah Well, in the actual function they're not being ToStringed, this was just a simplified example. I'll remove that to prevent confusion.

Comment: It remains that if you’re iterating over a `Tuple`, you don’t care about the individual types in the `Tuple` and they have some common functionality or base class, so use an array of that internally if you must.

Comment: You cannot use a `Tuple` like an array since it's not a collection. There's a `Tuple(Of T)` class, a `Tuple(Of T1, T2)` class .... and a `Tuple(Of T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest)` but all are not related through inheritance.

Comment: @rynah That works. Is it possible to enforce the number of elements in the array?

Comment: @Asad: You could check it! But if you use this internally, your method could still take a `Tuple`.

Comment: @rynah Right, but that check isn't compile time. I'm working with a team, so if I use an array, it is harder for someone who hasn't seen the function definition to understand what they need to pass it. That last statement is interesting. Do you mean to say I could accept a tuple and still somehow iterate over the contents?

Comment: @Asad: You would accept a `Tuple`, then create an array as `Dim a() As Object = {t.Item1, t.Item2, t.Item3}`, then loop over `a`.

Comment: @rynah I ended up using that and commenting in an explanation. When you find time, could you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sure, I’ll turn this into an answer!)

You can put the items into an array for convenience; maintaining the type isn’t really an issue at that point, since if you’re doing the same thing with all of them they need to have some sort of common base class or interface.

```
Dim a() As Object = {t.Item1, t.Item2, t.Item3}
```

Then just iterate over that.